# Папки с дополнительными NuGet пакетами для .net Core

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, nuget

Исходные данные: ПК без доступа к интернету, VS2017 и проект на .net Core.
На ПК есть общая "офлайн папка с пакетами", откуда черпаются все основные (например `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\`).
Вопрос: Можно ли проекту указать *дополнительную* папку, в которой бы брались пакеты, которые *не были найдены* в общей папке? Только для этого проекта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Папка `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\` представляет из себя [Local Feeds](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds) - папка с иерархичной структурой хранения nuget-пакетов, из которой можно устанавливать nuget-пакеты. 
Для того, чтобы подключить дополнительный [Local Feeds](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds) в проект, вы можете сделать:

1. На уровне папки проекта создайте файл `NuGet.Config`. В этом файле прописать следующее содержимое

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
        <add key="Test Source" value="c:\packages" />
      </packageSources>
   </configuration>
   ```

Элемент [packageSources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesources) содержит список источников для установки пакетов.

2. **Если вы используете NetCore2.0**, тогда путь до источника nuget-пакетов можно указать прямо в файле проекта(**csproj**) следующим образом

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
       <RestoreSources>$(RestoreSources);c:\packages;
            https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
       </RestoreSources>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

*Может то, а может не совсем, но тем не менее.*

---

Из [[Spec] Fallback package folders](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-Fallback-package-folders):

> Fallback package folders allow packages to be shared across users and
>   machines to reduce disk space. These folders are treated as fallback
>   folders for the primary global packages folder
>   (%USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages). They differ from package sources in
>   that the package assets will be referenced directly and will not be
>   copied into the user's packages folder.
>
> The concept of a fallback package folder can be thought of as a GAC
>   for nupkgs.

---

[[Spec] NuGet settings in MSBuild](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-NuGet-settings-in-MSBuild)

Свойство `RestoreFallbackFolders` -

> Fallback folders, these are used in the same way the user packages folder is used.

Свойство `RestoreAdditionalProjectFallbackFolders` -

> Additional fallback folders appended to the resulting list of fallback folders

---

Имеется пакет **NLog** в [global packages folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders). Если запустить сборку проекта, то в логах будет видно, что пакет подгружается из упомянутой директории:

```
1>    Primary reference "NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c".
1>        Resolved file path is "C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\nlog\4.5.7\lib\netstandard2.0\NLog.dll".
1>        Reference found at search path location "{HintPathFromItem}".
1>        This reference is not "CopyLocal" because at least one source item had "Private" set to "false" and no source items had "Private" set to "true".
1>        The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
```

Добавим в проект с помощью свойства `RestoreAdditionalProjectFallbackFolders` резервный источник:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RestoreAdditionalProjectFallbackFolders>C:\Users\username\Desktop\Username</RestoreAdditionalProjectFallbackFolders>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Удаляем **NLog** из [global packages folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) (в искомой "офлайн папке" пакета не оказалось) и запускаем сборку проекта:

```
1>    Primary reference "NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c".
1>        Resolved file path is "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Username\nlog\4.5.7\lib\netstandard2.0\NLog.dll".
1>        Reference found at search path location "{HintPathFromItem}".
1>        This reference is not "CopyLocal" because at least one source item had "Private" set to "false" and no source items had "Private" set to "true".
1>        The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
```

В рамках `restore` операции пакет подгружается из `FallbackFolder` если оный отсутствует в [global packages folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders), и не копируется в него по окончанию. Даже при наличии доступа к сети, пакет берется из `FallbackFolder`.

---

**UPD**: В случае использования [packageSources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesources) не до конца понятна ситуация с приоритетностью источников, ибо [тут](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5611#issuecomment-316153517) сказано, что:

> All feeds are queried and the one with the shortest response time wins.

Кроме того, пакеты из локального источника будут копироваться в [global packages folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders), т.е дублироваться.